# Load webpage's content after main load

Tags: javascript, ruby, performance, sinatra

### Scenario

I've got a website that fetches data from *x* server through a bunch of JSON files. This process takes about 1500ms which is ok, however if you go to the webpage that renders that data, it will take a while because it is waiting on that data the other process is getting.

### Tried "solutions"

#### Caching

This does work most times until there is new data that the website needs to get, there will then be a few users waiting on that load, the goal is to prevent that completely.

Comment: Load the page, fetch the data using AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to solve the problem that works better that loading the data after the page loads. Rather than fetching the data on page request, I request it periodically using a worker in a different thread which gives the app the data.